# send token / asset by cardano-CLI

Tags: cardano-cli, transaction, token, build, asset

i am looking so long, but till now didnt find a complete answer about :
how to send a token / asset from cardano-cli.
can you please help me to go in details about build the transaction from the CLI ?

1. cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
2. cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee
3. cardano-cli transaction build-raw
4. cardano-cli transaction sign
5. cardano-cli transaction submit

is the steps correct in high Level?
can we go in details to write the commands?

thank you in advanced,
Thomas
theTokenSquare17

Answer (score 2):

The `tx-out` of the `build-raw` command is the only thing that is different for sending assets. Instead of `address+1000000` it will be `address+"1000000 + 5 <policy id><<asset name>"`

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between building a regular ADA-only transaction and one that contains ADA + asset(s) is in the `cardano-cli transaction build-raw` step that follows the [multi-asset syntax as discussed in the official cardano documentation](https://docs.cardano.org/native-tokens/getting-started)

It would look something along the lines of:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
--tx-in <TX_ID> \
--fee <FEE> \
--tx-out <ADDRESS+LOVELACE+"NUMBER_OF_TOKEN(s) POLICYID" \
--out-file tx.raw
```

Note that in the `--tx-out` step, `LOVELACE` should be an integer value, and `"NUMBER_OF_TOKEN(s) POLICYID"` should all be a string.

The rest of the steps for caluclating min fees and signing/submitting should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for the link,
it was exactly what i needed and yes, it is righ.
used it, tested and worked

cardano-cli transaction build-raw 
--fee 0 
--tx-in ${tx_in} 
--tx-in ${my_tx_in} 
--tx-out ${in_addr}+${amountToSendUser}+"1 ${myToken}" 
--tx-out ${paymentAddr}+${amountToDonate}+"999 ${myToken}" 
--invalid-hereafter $FINALTIP 
--out-file tx.draft

fee=$(cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee 
--tx-body-file tx.draft 
--tx-in-count ${TXNS} 
--tx-out-count 2 
--witness-count 3 
--mainnet 
--protocol-params-file protocol.json

cardano-cli transaction build-raw 
--fee ${fee} 
--tx-in ${tx_in} 
--tx-in ${my_tx_in} 
--tx-out ${in_addr}+${amountToSendUser}+"1 ${myToken}" 
--tx-out ${paymentAddr}+${amountToReturn}+"999 ${myToken}" 
--invalid-hereafter $FINALTIP 
--out-file tx.raw

cardano-cli transaction sign 
--signing-key-file $paymentSignKeyPath 
--tx-body-file tx.raw 
--out-file tx.signed 
--mainnet

cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file tx.signed --mainnet